# Steam trade-offer-manager get items info shorten

Tags: javascript, node.js, steam, steambot

I'm trying to build a new project.
It's going to be a tradebot for a website, now to store my received items into my database i whould like some info send with each item (being the name , asseid , tradeid,...).
The following code works.

```
offers.on('receivedOfferChanged', function (offer, oldState) {
logger.info(offer.partner.getSteam3RenderedID() + " Offer #" + offer.id + " changed: " + TradeOfferManager.getStateName(oldState) + " -> " + TradeOfferManager.getStateName(offer.state));

// Alert us when we accept an offer
if (offer.state == TradeOfferManager.ETradeOfferState.Accepted) {
    offer.getReceivedItems(function (err, items) {
        if (err) {
            logger.error("Couldn't get received items: " + err);
        } else {
            var names = items.map(function(item) {
                return item.name;
            });
            var assetids = items.map(function(item) { 
                return item.assetid; 
            });
            // Log a comma-separated list of items received
            logger.info("Received: " + names + " " + assetids.join(', '));
        }
    });
}
});`
```

But the thing is, is there any way to shorten the following code :

```
var names = items.map(function(item) {
            return item.name;
        });
        var assetids = items.map(function(item) { 
            return item.assetid; 
        });
```

So it gets the item name , assetid, ... out of the array and stores them in sperate variables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method to add values into both arrays in a single loop. Try:

```
var names = [],
    assetids = [];

items.forEach(function(item) {
    assetids.push(item.assetid); 
    names.push(item.name); 
});
```

Comment: That worked like a charm man , thank you for the quick repley!